# Can you store a reference in a $GLOBAL variable

Tags: php

I know this is probably obvious. Just to confirm from some who has done it before:

Can you store a reference in a `$GLOBAL` variable? I plan to store an array of references in a `$GLOBAL` variable which can be accessed by a function several times.

Sorry I meant to say references instead of pointers.

Comment: Why do you ask if you can try it and check if it works?

Comment: What is `reference` and what is `pointer` in php context?

Comment: I am talking about this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

I assume the values in $GLOBALS array behave very much like $variable.

Comment: What do you mean with $GLOBAL? There is a superglobal variable named `$GLOBALS`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. That is what I am referring to. The superglobal variable $GLOBALS

Yes. I have tested it and tit appears to work. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but opt for a design that does not rely on global state. Maintenance & testing will be a lot easier in the long run.

Comment: careful with those typos. first the $GLOBAL, and now the tit appears to work which is nice, but a bit off-topic here...

Comment: I just don't understand questions of this type. A reference inside `$GLOBALS` is useless. It's as useful as a wrench when you're in the middle of a desert without water. That's how great it is. Instead of describing your **problem** and what you *think* you will solve by storing references inside `$GLOBALS`, you asked whether you can save references. Well yes, of course you can. But what the hell do they reference? Also, PHP alleviates many problems internally when it comes to performance and what not, and storing a reference there just might prove to be performance downgrade.

Comment: Explaining the entire problem I have will result in a very long explanation (which may not make sense). I just wanted to see how people feel about storing a &$ref in a superglobal and using globals. Now I know you can but now a good idea.

I am writing a small CMS and things get complicated when trying to predict what data developers will provide. I have written a function and I want a variable containing references to objects in an stdClass to be available in the function. The function will access the references and make changes.

Comment: Have you heard of Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection terms? If not, I strongly suggest to google them. That just might tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. No, you shouldn't.

Using globals in your application is unmaintainable and will cause you a lot of headache in the near/far future. There are plenty of resources about why global state is bad.